# Alter Table In Hive

Tags: hive

T1

table 1 has 2 rows say row a and b and having 3 columns C1, C2, C3 with the values as given below

```
C1    C2    C3 
 1    2    2
 3    5    6
```

how can i update the value of row b columns c2 i.e. 5 to 10, from difference (T2)legacy table via using hive?

T2

```
C1   C2   C3
 3   10   6
```